# Show TextView corresponding to button tag

Tags: java, android

I'm dynamically creating some buttons and some corresponding textviews underneath the buttons (button, textview, button, textview...) I want the textView to show when i press the button above it and hide again when i press the same button. I have given the same tags for the button and the matching textview.
I want it to work like this: Press button with tag1, show textview with tag1, press button again and it'll hide it. 
Right now it only shows and hides the last created textview when i press any of the buttons. 
UPDATED CODE:

```
    private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Button button1;
        TextView tv;
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            Log.i("JSON", "Number of surveys in feed: " +
            jsonArray.length());

            LinearLayout news = (LinearLayout)findViewById(id.hello);
            //---print out the content of the json feed---
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                button1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                button1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                button1.setId(i);
                tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setId(i);
                button1.setText(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                tv.setText(jsonObject.getString("text"));


                news.addView(button1);
                news.addView(tv);

                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        v.isPressed();
                            if(v.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                        } else {
                            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });



                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonObject.getString("title") +
                        " - " + jsonObject.getString("text"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, how do i call the variable tv in the onClick method. It wont let me add another view to the parameter, and i View v, is the view of the button. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you the variables tv and myButton are class members. If that is the case they will be overwritten at each step of the for-loop. This means that once the on click listener triggers it will refer to the most recently set values for tv and myButton (ie the last step of the for-loop).

Change tv and myButton into variables within the method scope and either combine createButton() and createTextView() into a single method or let createTextView() return the created TextView and pass that to createButton()

I've made some changes to your code:

- Moved the Button and TextView declarations inside the for-loop
- Changed the onClick listener to use the local TextView reference.

PS I'm not sure why you called v.isPressed() inside onClick(). It does nothing.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        Log.i("JSON", "Number of surveys in feed: " +
        jsonArray.length());

        LinearLayout news = (LinearLayout)findViewById(id.hello);
        //---print out the content of the json feed---
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            final Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            button.setId(i);
            button.setText(jsonObject.getString("title"));

            final TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setId(i);
            tv.setText(jsonObject.getString("text"));

            news.addView(button);
            news.addView(tv);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tv.setVisibility(tv.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonObject.getString("title") +
                    " - " + jsonObject.getString("text"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have added tv and myButton to the scope now and combined the two create methods. Now the problem is, how do I get the onClick method to include the textview. When I'm only allowed to have one view inside my onClick.